# Display post links under month in paginated archive

Tags: pagination, archives, date-time

I'd like to create an archive that lists posts under a month header. The months would just be plain text and the post titles, obviously, would link to the posts themselves!

So:

**October 2013**

- Post title 1
- Post title 2

**September 2013**

- Post title 1
- Post title 2

**August 2013**

- Post title 1
- Post title 2

. . . and, if possible, only show one year per page! So, uhhh, I guess it's paginated too.

Is this possible? Probably. I've seen a few threads that deal with similar requests, but nothing quite like this. Or maybe I'm just bad at searching.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found which I'll break up into pieces:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $month = date("n", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
    $year = date("Y", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
```

The `for` loop will loop through how many months we want to pull, which in this case is 12. The `$month` variable will hold an integer without any leading zeros that we can use to reference the current (inside loop current) month later. I'm using `strtotime` to start at 1st day of the current (Real Time) month and count backwards from there. The same thing will happen with `$year`

```
$tmpQuery = new WP_Query(array('monthnum' => $month, 'post-type' => 'post'));
```

We can then use the `$month` variable to query all posts in that month. Then we can go into our normal loop.

```
<?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $month = date("n", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
        $year = date("Y", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));

        $tmpQuery = new WP_Query(array('monthnum' => $month, 'year' => $year, 'post-type' => 'post'));

        if($tmpQuery->have_posts()) :
        ?>
            <h2><?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10)); ?> - <?php echo $year; ?></h2>
            <ul>

            <?php while($tmpQuery->have_posts()) : $tmpQuery->the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>No Posts This Month</p> 
        <?php endif; 
        // wp_reset_query();
    }
?>
```

Comment: certainly there's a more efficient way to do this than running a separate query for every month.

Comment: @Milo That's what I thought, but `wp_get_archives` only brings month links and he wants posts per month. The only thing I wasn't certain about was paging them by year. Any idea on how to improve this?

Comment: you could do just one query per page/year. to organize by month, just check the month of each post and output the month header when it doesn't match the month of the previous post.